# scroll to middle of screen Horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am a newbie and  have read this code somewhere and i am not able to understand it.
Actually the point is that the code is trying to make the horizontal gallery were if a img is clicked then it will scroll to the center of screen.
here is the jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#topThumbs li").click(function () {

        var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width() / 2;
        var index = $(this).index();
        var thisImg = $("#thumbsList li img:eq(" + index + ")");
        var imagewidth = thisImg.width() / 2;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollLeft: ((thisImg.offset().left) - windowWidth + imagewidth)
        }, 1300);
    });
});
```

Now i am trying to do that in pure javascript. 
I am not able to figure how it is done.

Firstly, Window size is captured and it's half is done
 Then, the image size is captured and it's half is done..
**But i am not able to understand what** the `scrollleft`: is doing.
please help me.
thanks.

Comment: Have you read https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft?

Comment: no. But please can you tell me how this is happening?

Comment: Basically it scrolls the body page horizontally to view the image. So, I assume that the 'body content width' > 'window width'

Comment: @choz please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: @Tushar no jquery but only want to use Pure Js

Comment: Its easier to explain if you can share the link where that script comes from. Or create a fiddle out of it.

Comment: @Choz i just got it from archives for a computer...